# Base url in joomla module

Tags: url, joomla

Evening,

I've implented some AJAX functions in a Joomla module. Now when I activate SEF, the AJAX is not working anymore. This is because the path to the external php file is changed..To fix this I need to add the base url, now the question is: how to get the base url in the following:

```
remote: "modules/mod_module/libs/elements/db_checker.php"
```

so it should be something like

```
remote: "<?php echo $baseurl; ?>modules/mod_module/libs/elements/db_checker.php"
```

so the full link should become

```
remote: "http://www.mysite.com/modules/mod_module/libs/elements/db_checker.php"
```

I cant get URI to work, please assist me with this

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

fixed it myself:) this is the fix:

```
<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_module/libs/elements/db_checker.php'; ?>
```

Comment: You should add your fix as an answer and accept it in order to officialy mark it as solved ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

fixed it myself:) this is the fix:

```
<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_module/libs/elements/db_checker.php'; ?>
```